# Mysql select rows with same table not in where clause

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables like this:

Table 1

```
+----+-----------+--------------------+
| ID | Postcode4 |     woonplaats     |
+----+-----------+--------------------+
|  1 |      9044 | Beetgum            |
|  2 |      9045 | Beetgummermole     |
|  3 |      1028 | Amsterdam          |
|  4 |      1029 | Amsterdam          |
|  5 |      1030 | Amsterdam          |
+----+-----------+--------------------+
```

Table 2

```
+----+------+-------+
| ID | 4PP  | Regio |
+----+------+-------+
|  1 | 9044 |     2 |
|  2 | 9045 |     2 |
|  3 | 1028 |     4 |
|  4 | 1029 |     4 |
|  5 | 1030 |     4 |
+----+------+-------+
```

I first want to select the regio in wicht Beetgum is, in this case regio 2. Then i want all the other 4PP in table 2 wich have the same regio (2). So the outcome of the query has to be 9044,9045

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And here is a joined one :)

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.4PP = Table1.Postcode4
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.Regio = Table2.regio
WHERE Table1.woonplaats = 'Beetgum'
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/347f3/3

Comment: Yep! But not fast... Almost 1 second query. Where is the best place for a index? Woonplaats or 4PP?

Comment: sqlfiddle. This is my favorite post of the day. I had not heard of this.

Comment: @MikeC. and the best thing, you can actually paste the nice ascii art table and get a DDL!

Comment: @hank: That's awesome...did not know you could do that.

Comment: Awesome! Index on the woonplaats (VARCHAR) and the query runs in 0,0011 sec in stead of 0,912 sec

Answer (score 1):

Here's a really crappy query until someone gives you a fancy joined one (which you should then use)

```
select t.4PP from Table2 t
WHERE t.Regio in
(
  select Regio
  from Table2 t2
  join Table1 t1 on t2.4PP=t1.Postcode4
  where t1.woonplats='Beetgum'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
select 4PP from table2 where Regio in (select Regio from table2 where 4PP in (select PostCode4 from table1 where woonplaats = "Beetgum"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Table3.4PP) 4PP FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON(Table1.PostCode4 = Table2.4PP) 
INNER JOIN Table2 AS Table3 ON(Table2.Regio = Table3.Regio) 
WHERE woonplaats = 'Beetgum';
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7b406/4)